# How to use a variable in a select query postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, variables, select, procedure

So here is my problem,

I have a procedure with :

```
    DECLARE
serialvar INTEGER;

BEGIN
serialvar := NEW.battery_serial;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW battery_vue
AS
SELECT * FROM cells WHERE battery_serial = serialvar;
RETURN NEW;
END;
```

but when the trigger of that procedure is activated i have an error saying :

> ERROR:  the column « serialvar » does not exist
>
> LINE 3: SELECT * FROM cells WHERE battery_serial = serialVar

Comment: Maybe you need `TEMPORARY VIEW`? It will be dropped at the end of session **and will not conflict with other sessions.** Details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the value into a dynamic SQL like

```
BEGIN

EXECUTE $$CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW battery_vue
AS
SELECT * FROM cells WHERE battery_serial = $$ || NEW.battery_serial;

RETURN NEW;

END;
```

this way you take the new value, and if it is 1 (for example), then `battery_vue` will show you only the `cells` where `battery_serial = 1`.  Is this what you want?  (The next insert or whatever will recreate the view, possibly with a different `battery_serial`.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer it works !, yes i want the view to show only Battery_serials = 1